# If year and month match then make calculation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have formula to check if months match. If so then make correct calculation. I need to add one more statement so that formula would also compare years and some numbers would appear in year 2020 section, under correct month. I have tried with `AND(I$1=MONTH($P$19);I$1=YEAR($P$19))` but cant really get it work.

In `$P$19` I have 6.3.2019

In `$P$20` I have 6.3.2020

In `$D$11`, `$D$12`, `$D$13`, `$D$14` I have numbers 1,2,3,4

In `$AB2` number 1000

1...12 are months in each year

This is formula example from cell I2:

```
=IF(I$1=MONTH($P$19)-1;$AB2*$D$11;IF(I$1=MONTH($P$19);$AB2*$D$12;IF(I$1=MONTH($P$20);$AB2*$D$13;IF(I$1=MONTH($P$20)+1;$AB2*$D$14;0))))
```

[image]

Comment: `AND(I$1=MONTH($P$19);I$1=YEAR($P$19))` doesn't check the year column (`H`) try `AND(I$1=MONTH($P$19);$H2=YEAR($P$19))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sur I fully understood what you are trying to achiev, but
the AND addition you've tried out still links to the month so instead of

```
AND(I$1=MONTH($P$19);I$1=YEAR($P$19))
```

try

```
AND(I$1=MONTH($P$19);$H2=YEAR($P$19))
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(VLOOKUP(I1;$D$11:$D$15;1;0)=MONTH($P$19);$H3=YEAR($P$19));$AB$2*VLOOKUP(I1;$D$11:$D$15;1;0);0);0)
```

[image]

I hope this helps!